# Function to remove repeated characters from a string only partially works with adjacent characters

Tags: c++, string

I know that this is an oft asked question and apologize if it is dumb, but I'm trying to remove duplicated characters from a strings in a file and put the new strings into another file. That part is going fine.

The main problem I'm having is with my algorithm to remove the characters it only works with consecutive characters that are the same and even then it only partially. I'm trying to user`.erase()` within a for-loop to do so, but as I said it isn't working. Where am I going wrong?

```
string removeRepeats(string strIn,string &strOut){
    int i;
    int len = strIn.length();
    for(i = 0;i < len; i++){
        if(strIn[i] == strIn[i+1]){
            strIn.erase(i+1,1);
        }
        len = strIn.length();
    }
    return strOut = strIn;
}
```

These are the strings from my input strings from the sample file:

```
aaaaaabbccccc
nnnnmmmvvv
rocko 
refrigerate pool 
fungus
```

This is what they come out as after the program runs:

```
aaabccc                                                                                                                                                 
nnmmvv                                                                                                                                                  
rocko                                                                                                                                                   
refrigerate                                                                                                                                             
pol                                                                                                                                                     
fungus
```

Comment: Well, you're only checking adjacent characters... `strIn[i] == strIn[i+1'`

Comment: Use an array of size 26.  Keep track of each letter you've seend by setting the appropriate element in the array.  The index into the array is = (your_letter - 'a').

Comment: If the characters are duplicated but not consecutive, is it removed as well? example : `aba`. What is the output? `aba` or `ab`?

Comment: It outputs `ba`? That is awfully strange behavior... That means once you see a repeat you have to loop through the string again.

Answer (score 2):

You're only checking adjacent characters: `if(strIn[i] == strIn[i+1]) { ...`

You can do this much more efficiently, but I want to make some comments first:

## Return *or* pass by reference, but not both

- You return `strOut` *and* pass `strOut` by reference. You should pick one or the other. In the code I wrote below, I chose to return `strOut`.

## Minimize the scope of your variables

- Unlike C, in C++ you can initialize variables in `for`-loops. You'll also want to attempt to minimize the scope of other variables besides loop variables. In your code you create a variable `len`. If you used `for(size_t i = 0; i < strIn.length(); ++i)` instead, you wouldn't need to update it after the `if`-statement.

## Returning an assignment is just plain *weird*

- `return strOut = strIn;` is pretty strange. You won't see this often in C++ (see **Return *or* pass by reference, but not both**). If you really wanted to `return strOut`, it would make more sense to create a copy of `strIn` before you change it and do all of your string-mutations on the copy.

Here are the changes I would make to your code (regardless of the correctness of the algorithm):

```
std::string removeRepeats(std::string strIn){
    std::string strOut = strIn;
    for(size_t i = 0;i < strOut.length(); ++i){
        if(strOut[i] == strOut[i+1]){
            strOut.erase(i+1,1);
        }
    }
    
    return strOut; 
}
```

This is much cleaner, you'll find.

## Now to fixing your problem.

Since there are only 128 ASCII characters, you can make a boolean array and check if you've seen a certain character before.

Because you want to keep the *last* of the repeated characters, we will need to be a little tricky. Below is code that will keep the *first* of the repeated characters.

## C++11 approved

```
std::string remove_repeats(std::string input_string) {
  // You have seen no characters yet
  bool seen[128] = { false }; 
  
  std::string output_string = "";

  // for every character in the string
  for(auto c: input_string) {
    // if we haven't seen the the ASCII yet
    if(!seen[128-c]) {
      // append it to our output string
      output_string+=c;
      // mark the letter as seen
      seen[128-c] = true;
    }
  }
   
  return output_string;
}
```

Here's the [ideone](https://ideone.com/uwd590).

If you can't use C++11, you can do this:

```
std::string remove_repeats(std::string input_string) {
  // You have seen no characters yet
  bool seen[128] = { false };  
  
  std::string output_string = "";

  // for every character in the string
  for(size_t i = 0; i < input_string.length(); ++i) {
    char c = input_string[i];
    // if we haven't seen the the ASCII yet
    if(!seen[128-c]) {
      // append it to our output string
      output_string+=c;
      // mark the letter as seen
      seen[128-c] = true;
    }
  }
   
  return output_string;
}
```

Here's the [ideone](https://ideone.com/rvIlZA) for the non-C++11 version.

## However

You want to keep the last. Here's where it gets fun.

If we reverse the string (1), run our algorithm (2), then re-reverse (3), we'll get the desired output:

> (1) "hello world" -> "dlrow olleh"
>
> (2) "dlrow olleh" -> "dlrow eh"
>
> (3) "dlrow eh" -> "he world"

Here's how to do this:

```
std::string remove_repeats(std::string input_string) {
  // You have seen no characters yet
  bool seen[128] = { false };  

  // Reverse the input string
  std::reverse(input_string.begin(), input_string.end());
  
  std::string output_string = "";

  // for every character in the string
  for(auto c: input_string) {
    // if we haven't seen the the ASCII yet
    if(!seen[128-c]) {
      // append it to our output string
      output_string+=c;
      // mark the letter as seen
      seen[128-c] = true;
    }
  }

  // Reverse the output string
  std::reverse(output_string.begin(), output_string.end());

  return output_string;
}
```

Be sure to `#include <algorithm>` for `std::reverse`.

Final working [ideone](https://ideone.com/aFM3Li)

Comment: but this won't return `ba` for `aba` as OP wants.

Comment: @rcs Edited to fix OP's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

so what you need to do is when looking for repeat chars is you a nested for loop inside your existing for loop so:

```
string removeRepeats(string strIn,string &strOut){
int i;
int k;
int len = strIn.length();
for(i = 0;i < len; i++){
    for(k = i+1 ; k < len; k++){

        if(strIn[i] == strIn[k]){
            strIn.erase(k,1);
            k--;
        }
    }
    len = strIn.length();
}
return strOut = strIn;
}
```

this will fix the comparing part of your program. your problem was in that your code only checked each number with the one immediately following it instead of all other characters

Comment: This is `O(n^2)`. Can do better.

Comment: @ erip what do you mean?

Comment: you use 2 nested loops. that's `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Your suggestion makes the program returns: `aabcc` and `nnmmvv` for the strings that aren't actually words.

Comment: `i++` in second loop should be `k++` and you need to either decrement `k` when a match is found or only increment it when a match isn't found.

Comment: opps sorry, did that answer quickly while my gf was trying to call for my attention, guess I missed those two things

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Would you mind explaining this answer? I don't wanna use it and not understand how it work.

Comment: your first loop sets i to 0, the nested loop sets k to i+1 so that it is not comparing any cell to itself, then it proceeds to loop through the rest of the list as k values to check them all against strIn[i] before moving back to the outside loop and increasing the i value. the k--  is thrown in there because when you delete a cell the rest of the list moves back to take its place and if we were to allow k to advance like normal then we would end up skipping the check on cells directly after a deleted value. hope this helped let me know if you need more clarification.